# Comprobar si un input es str, int o float

Tags: python, python-3.x

Otra vez yo, iniciando en esto de `python`.

Quisiera saber como hacer para comprobar si un `input` es un `string`, un `integer` o un decimal, tengo entendido que existen las funciones `.isalpha()`,`isdigit()` y `isalnum()` pero no encuentro cual seria para verificar si es un decimal.

Intente, haciendo lo siguiente:

```
print("<---------------------------------------->")
        polygon.color= input("introduce el color que deseas: ")
        print(polygon.color)
        if int(polygon.color):
            print("numero")
        elif float(polygon.color):
            print("decimal")
        elif str(polygon.color):
            print("string")
```

Si pongo en el `input` por ejemplo: `"3"`, me dice que es un numero. si pongo por ejemplo: `"2.3"`, me lanza el siguiente error :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.3'
```

Si pongo por ejemplo: `"rojo"`, me lanza el mismo error(`ValueError`).

Mi idea es que obligue al usuario a introducir un valor `str` y no otro.

Comment: **`input` por definición siempre retorna una cadena**, `str(poligon.color)` no tiene sentido, ya es un objeto `str` de partida. Otra cosa es que la cadena se pueda o no convertir a `int` o `float`. Cuando dices  "obligue al usuario a introducir un valor `str` y no otro."  no queda muy claro que quieres, porque el usuario siempre ingresa una cadena, el problema viene cuando intentas convertirla a `int` o `float`. "1.2.2" no es un entero ni un float válido, pero ¿lo considerarías una entrada válida?

Comment: Sería interesante saber para qué quieres limitar a que el usuario use un str. La respuesta de DannyTalent puede utilizarse para validar si la cadena es un str o un número. Pero para lo que creo que quieres hacer creo que puedes dar un paso más allá. Para qué necesitas un color? Vas a plotear con matplotlib, o generar algo en html, o qué?

Comment: Por favor, esclarece mejor tu pregunta. Escribe correctamente qué es lo que deseas que haga tu programa, ¿Qué tipo de str deseas que acepte y cuáles no?

Comment: okey, en un principio declare que soy principiante en esto de python. Ahora tengo en claro que una funcion del tipo int() o str(), etc, es para convertir el valor que esta dentro de los parentesis en el valor que dice la funcion. Cuando publique esto creia que eso me iba a devolver un True o False dependiendo de si el valor dentro de los parentesis era un valor del tipo int, str, etc.
Mi idea es que el usuario introduzca un color, como bien dice, y no algo como "rojo9" , tampoco "23", sino "rojo".
@JACH , lo que estaba haciendo era una practica para probar las clases y atributos en python.

Comment: Ok. Porque Python te ofrece todavía más flexibilidad. Podrías por ejemplo preguntar si el argumento que recibiste pertenece a los colores de matplotlib, por ejemplo. Matas dos pájaros de un tiro.

Comment: Cree una pregunta paralela a tu pregunta. Me parece que lo que querías saber es si el usuario había escrito un color válido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277520/comprobar-si-un-string-es-un-color-válido-de-matplotlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu pregunta dices:

> "Mi idea es que obligue al usuario a introducir un valor `str` y no
>   otro."

Se puede solucionar con expresiones regulares, de la siguiente manera y sin utilizar mucho código:

```
import re

while True:
    color = input("introduce el color que deseas: ")

    if re.search('[0-9]', color):
        continue

    break
```

Así cada ves que en encuentre un numero en el rango de números establecidos, en el `string` se repetirá el bucle y así sucesivamente hasta que ingrese un valor valido.

Lo que quiero decir es que así introduzcas decimales, en el `string` nunca sera valido, porque un decimal o `float` contiene números.

Prácticamente el `string` no tiene que tener ningún numero para así ser valido y como consecuencia se romperá el bucle y podrá continuar ejecutándose el programa con normalidad.

Comment: que diferencia hay entre usar re a que usar un `for` que recorra el `string` buscando un numero del 0 al 9?

Comment: Las expresiones regulares son una secuencia de caracteres que forman un patrón de búsqueda, que sirven para el trabajo y procesamiento de texto. En este caso estamos buscando coincidencias o una búsqueda como tal, en el `input`, coincidencias en el rango del 0 al 9.

Comment: Para mas información visita la documentación oficial: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Lucho,
Cuando haces que Python intente cambiar algo que no es un número a int o a float, te va a dar un error (¿Qué dirías si te preguntan qué número es la palabra "arroz"?, por ejemplo). Para tu caso, puedes usar el try...except, que cuando te salga el error (ValueError), sabrás que como no se pudo convertir a número, ocurrió un error, es decir, el usuario no ingresó lo que buscas.

Además lo puse en un while (significa algo como "mientras que la siguiente condición sea verdad, hacer lo que está debajo") y con un booleano `f` para que siga preguntando lo mismo hasta que el usuario te de un valor adecuado

```
print("<---------------------------------------->")
f=True
while f:
    polygon.color= input("introduce el color que deseas: ")
    print(polygon.color)
    try:
        if int(polygon.color):
            print("numero")
        elif float(polygon.color):
            print("decimal")
        else:
            print("string")
            f=False #Para salir del while
    except ValueError:
        print('Ingresaste un color invalido')
```

No he probado el código, pero debería funcionar

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla que se me hizo de lograr la solución fue aplicar lo siguiente:

```
while True:

    print("<---------------------------------------->")
    polygon.color= input("introduce el color que deseas: ")

    if (polygon.color.isdigit() or polygon.color.isalpha()==False):

        print("el valor ingresado no es correcto")
        continue

    break
```

Gracias a todos por su ayuda

Answer (score -1):

Cuando ejecutas

```
>>>>a=input("ingresar algo:  " )
ingresar algo:
```

el resultado siempre es un string, puedes comprobarlo haciendo

```
>>>>type(a)
<class 'str'>
```

Si tienes una variable y deseas comprobar si es string debes hacer una comparación `type(a)==str` o si deseas comprobar si es decimal puedes crear una pequeña función:

```
def isdecimal( value):
    val=float(value)
    s=val-int(val)
    if s==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: creo que no termino de entender la parte en el que empiezas con def, se que es una funcion pero... el valor val de donde sale? no esta mal escrito? no termino de entender lo que hace s ni val

Comment: @LuchoK tienes razón, el objetivo de `val` es que puedas ingresar también un string como número