# Comprobar si un string es un color válido de matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Inspirado por la pregunta formulada [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277016/comprobar-si-un-input-es-str-int-o-float), decidí responder a la pregunta: cómo saber si un string es un color válido de matplotlib

El código sería:

```
def is_color(color):
    # Return TRUE if color is a valid matplotlib color, False otherwise
```

Answer (score 4):

La lista de colores de matplotlib se puede obtener de la siguiente manera:

```
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

list_of_colors = list(mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.keys())
```

Una vez que tenemos la lista, verificar que el color sea parte de ella es sencillo

```
def is_color(color):
    return color in list_of_colors

print(is_color("black"))
```

o tal como sugiere FJSevilla, simplemente

```
if "black" in list_of_colors:
    # Do as you please
```

Comment: Solo un comentario, `return[color in list_of_colors]`
 crea una lista con un boleano, haz simplemente `return color in list_of_colors`. No obstante, 
si solo quieres comprobar si el color es válido, es mucho más eficiente hacer la búsqueda en el propio diccionario. No es necesaria la lista: `return color in mcolors.CSS4_COLORS`. Un saludo.

Comment: Tienes razón, está regresando una lista. Edito el cambio. Respecto a la función, ciertamente no es necesario. Sólo lo hice para ser un poco más explícito